# Using the Arrow Operator in Struct Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am a beginner in C, mainly transitioning from C++. Here, I have some code here that I am trying to analyze, specifically the last few lines. After the array is created, how does the array appear to look? I am a little confused, mainly because of the array using the dot operator for an index for **both** x and y. What does that really do or create? Also, why is the value of x at the end 0? Shouldn't ind reach a value of 4, which in theory should then be the value of x?
Thank you!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
    
    
    #define NUMPOINT 5
    typedef struct
    {
      int x;
      int y;
    } Point;
    
    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      Point * arr;
      int ind;
    
     
      
      arr = malloc( NUMPOINT * sizeOf(*arr));
      if(arr == NULL)
      {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    
      // initialize the attributes
      for (ind = 0; ind < NUMPOINT; ind ++)
      {
        arr[ind].x = ind;
        arr[ind].y = ind * ind + 5;
      }

      Point * pptr = arr;
      
      printf("x = %d\n", pptr->x);
```

Comment: `(*arr)` You dereference an unitialized pointer variable here.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers, it makes it impossible to copy/paste it.

Comment: @Raildex It's not being dereferenced when used inside `sizeof`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. If you're already familiar with C++, this is the same.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on line 21.

Comment: `pptr` has the same value as `arr`, they both point to the first element of the array. The value of `ind` has no effect on `pptr->x`.

Comment: So my understanding is that pptr is a pointer of the struct Point, and is being set equal to the array arr. Then when pptr->x is called, it only looks at the [0] index of arr? Which should in turn be zero

Comment: @aerialace8 That is correct: `pptr->x` points to `arr[0].x`. And `(pptr+1)->x` points to `arr[1].x`. See how they're just different ways of addressing the same memory location?